# Trouble with local install of bower

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower

I installed bower locally in project, creating a folder 'node_modules' and 'bower' in it. then I run bower on the command line:

```
$ bower
bower: команда не найдена (command not found)
```

Why is this? if I install bower globally everything works correctly.

Comment: If you install bower globally you will be able to use the `bower` command. Although you can also use the locally installed bower like so: `./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install`

Comment: Yep, install it globally with `npm install -g bower`

Answer (score 8):

#### How to install Bower ([from the docs](http://bower.io/#installing-bower)):

```
npm install -g bower
```

The important part is the `-g` flag, as that informs npm to install it "globally". This means that npm will create a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the bower binary<sup>*</sup> in your Node.js binaries folder (which is in your `PATH`). This allows your shell (be it Bash, zsh, csh, etc.) to find the command.

#### Why won't it work if you run `npm install bower`?

Just running `npm install bower` installs the given package into the current folder under `node_modules/{package}`. If you do this and try running `bower` from the command line, your shell won't know where to find the `bower` command because it is not in your `PATH` (hence the "command not found" error).

As @Jason noted in the comments, you can explicitly run the bower binary<sup>*</sup> by running `./node_modules/bower/bin/bower`. When run like this, your shell will know where to find the command. You can, if needed, alias that to something shorter:

```
alias bower="./node_modules/bower/bin/bower"
```

---

<sup>*</sup> I use the word binary extremely loosely. It's more a file marked as being executable with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) atop it.

Comment: Oddly, I get this error when I perform these instructions: `bower EINVALID      The name has to end with a lower case character from a to z`. *EDIT*: To solve this, all I needed was a bower.json file with at least the 'required' fields completed.